# SQL Convert GETUTCDATE to nvarchar timezone like 'Eastern Standard Time'

Tags: sql, datetime

I would like to convert a `GETUTCDATE()` call to a timezone using a timezone string like 'Eastern Standard Time' or any timezone string located in the registry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`.  Is there a method to do that or am I venturing into SQLCLR territory?

Current suggestions I've seen:

```
print CONVERT(datetime2, DATEADD(HOUR, -4, GETUTCDATE()))
```

Output:

```
2015-09-08 15:22:50.5000000
```

I'd like to see this with DST working.

Is something like this possible?

```
print CONVERT(datetime2, DATEADD(HOUR, 'Eastern Standard Time', GETUTCDATE()))
```

I have SQL Server 2012 Standard available to me. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check out [`DATETIMEOFFSET` datatype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) which is a datetime datatype that **includes** that timezone.

Also, there's a [function called `SWITCHOFFSET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) which allows you to switch a given `DATETIMEOFFSET` to another timezone.

With those two pieces, you can do:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDateTime DATETIMEOFFSET

SELECT @CurrentDateTime = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()

DECLARE @OtherDateTime DATETIMEOFFSET

SELECT @OtherDateTime = SWITCHOFFSET(@CurrentDateTime, `-05:00')
```

Comment: Thank you marc_s for your comment.  I will use this data type.  This gets me very close!  The last part I need is for the '-05:00' to be something like 'Pacific Standard Time'.  I have that string value stored (any timezone LIKE 'Pacific Standard Time') and was hoping to get away from looking up on a static value.

Comment: @Cactuar167: I don't think SQL Server has any built-in support for this. You might need to create a lookup table yourself, that contains the clear text time zones like `Pacific Standard Time` and track what time offset that time zone has, to use that time offset with `SWITCHOFFSET`

Comment: Thanks again marc_s, this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'

This returns datetime with offset in zone you specify. This can easly converted to datetime, datetime2